# HTML pagescroll error

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-pagescroller

My page scroll is not working, can anyone suggest solution for below code,..

```
<div id="ascrail2001" class="nicescroll-rails" style="width: 6px; z-index: 1000; cursor: default; position: fixed; top: 0px; height: 100%; right: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(64, 64, 64);">
    <div style="position: relative; top: 0px; float: right; width: 6px; height: 32px; border-radius: 10px; background-color: rgb(232, 64, 63); background-clip: padding-box;">
</div>
</div>
```

thanks...

Comment: "Not working".  Are you a project manager?

Comment: tip: to be able to scroll your page, it has to actually contain something.

Comment: @im1dermike i'm a beginner

Comment: @Fyodoro: The more information you give, the easier it is for us to help.

Comment: i just using above code for page scrolling along with nicescroll js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem i faced, because i add the js file in the beginning of the code. now i changed it and solved my problem. silly mistake. thanks guys @banana, @im1dermike and @lisztomania

Answer (score 2):

Remove `position: fixed;`

or

Add `overflow:scroll;` to inner box.

Also has Banana said, you should have content(text, images...) in your div.

Comment: Why downvote ? It won't work with a "position: fixed;" even with text/content inside...
Another solution: The inner div can have "overflow:scroll"

Comment: the downvote because its not an answer, but rather a comment.

Comment: Thanks for edit Banana, and for the Apostrophe ' tips for the code

Comment: you're welcome. and its not an apostrophe, its a grave accent :)